# Source NAT rule for LXC containers

Tags: iptables, lxc, nat

I've just noticed that `MASQUERADE` `iptables` rule added by `lxc` has `! -d` part:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.3.0/24 ! -d 10.0.3.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

My guess is that `-s 10.0.3.0/24 -d 10.0.3.0/24` can only be observed when sending data from one container to the other one (`ping`, `ssh`, you name it). And omitting the `! -d` part can only affect performance. To unknown extent. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule allows two different containers on the same subnet to talk to each other without being NAT'd

So a container with 10.0.3.100 talking to 10.0.3.101 will appear as 10.0.3.100 to the other container and not as the host address.

This can be beneficial for various purposes (e.g. logging of activity, access controls) because the target container can identify the source container.  It also allows these containers to not need default routes (it's all local subnet) so can be beneficial from a security perspective.

And, of course, it removes unnecessary NAT overhead!

Comment: I just tried to run two LXC containers (`10.0.0.100`, `10.0.0.200`) on local machine with `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE`, `tcpdump icmp` on one, `ping -c 1 10.0.0.100` on the other. And `tcpdump` says the IP is `10.0.0.200`.

Comment: I was told that by default iptables doesn't process inter-container traffic, but that can be enabled [system-wide](https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/masquerade-rule-added-by-lxc/3651/2?u=x-yuri).

Comment: Yeah, it's part of the "defensive configuration"; build for the worst case (what if...) so that changes made elsewhere don't break the local stuff.

Comment: Afaik this NAT avoidance wouldn't be needed with "normal" settings because the two containers are bridged, not routed. It could happen when [`br_netfilter`](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/bridge-nf.html) is activated, according to explanation below fig 7b in [ebtables/iptables interaction on a Linux-based bridge](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html#section7)